# Grails external configuraiton issue

Tags: grails

[Externalizing Grails Datasource configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970133/externalizing-grails-datasource-configuration)

i have followed the steps in answered section of above question.

```
grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:appconfig.properties"]
```

and placed `appconfig.properties` in `conf` folder. But this configuration is loading. what is the most trusted way to load external database configruation in grails ?  My grails version is 1.3.7.

EDIT:

Just now i have changed this code to

```
 grails.config.locations = ["file:${userHome}/.grails/appconfig.groovy"]
```

and placed the config file in .grails folder in my home folder. it is working in GGTS and war file also.

Answer (score 0):

Your config is not loaded when running with grails run-app? Or in deployment on tomcat? Or either?

[Try to look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807267/grails-external-configuration-grails-config-locations-absolute-path-file)

Comment: In both dev and deployment also the classpath option not working

Comment: Please post your BuildConfig.groovy and DataSource.groovy